# how to get table schema of already created table in xampp mysql server

Tags: mysql

I have already created some table in xampp mysql server.So can I copy or export the schema of those tables.Actually I am using nodejs and i came to know that there is a sequelize pakage to work with mysql queries easily But it requires the table schemas to work.
Is there some way to get their schemas of those already created tables in xampp??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use following Mysql Query in phpMyAdmin and it will give you the query to create table

```
SHOW CREATE TABLE TABLE_NAME
```

Comment: thanks a lot!, When I executed the query it showed me partial results and then I selected 'full text' option from 'Option' and it showed me complete schema.